# Laravel-5.7 : How to view data in dataset chart in Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, charts, laravel-5.7

I want to display data from the `controller` and throw it in the view as a dataset, but I have trouble how to write a loop on `scriptjava`.

This is the code that I have tried, and still fails

### This my controller :

```
laravel
    $query =  DB::table('app_history_calls')
              ->SELECT(DB::raw("(MONTH(date)) as bulan"))
              ->GROUPBY('date',DB::raw("MONTH(date)"))
              ->ORDERBY('date','asc')->get();


            return view('dashboard.index',compact('query'));
        }
```

### and this my view:

```
laravel
 <script type="text/javascript">

var month= [
<?php foreach ($query as $bulan): ?>

 <?php echo (string)$bulan ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
];
</script>
```

I expected the result will be like this:

> `"var month= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];"`

So that it can be read on the `dataset`

Comment: Your query perfectly working? Does it give an array month? and why you write php code in the script.

Comment: Why not ???????

Answer (score 1):

```php
  $data['query'] =  DB::table('app_history_calls')
              ->SELECT(DB::raw("(MONTH(date)) as bulan"))
              ->GROUPBY('date',DB::raw("MONTH(date)"))
              ->ORDERBY('date','asc')->get();


            return view('dashboard.index')->withdata($data);
        }
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var month= [
<?php foreach ($data['query'] as $bulan): ?>

 <?php echo (string)$bulan ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
];
</script>
```

Replace above code with your code i passed value in $data array and in for loop read `$data['query']` in js

Comment: (2/2) ErrorException
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string